# Query by coordinates takes too long - options to optimize?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, postgis

I have a table where I store events (about 5M at the moment, but there will be more). Each event has two attributes that I care about for this query - `location` (latitude and longitude pair) and `relevancy`.

**My goal is**: For a given location bounds (SW / NE latitude/longitude pairs, so 4 floating point numbers) return the top 100 events by `relevancy` which fall within those bounds.

I'm currently using the following query:

```
select * 
from event 
where latitude >= :swLatitude 
and latitude <= :neLatitude 
and longitude >= :swLongitude 
and longitude <= :neLongitude 
order by relevancy desc 
limit 100
```

Let's put aside for the moment the issue of date-line wrap-around which this query doesn't handle.

This works fine for smaller location bounds, but lags rather badly whenever I try to use larger location bounds.

I've defined the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX latitude_longitude_relevancy_index
  ON event
  USING btree
  (latitude, longitude, relevancy);
```

The table itself is quite straightforward:

```
CREATE TABLE event
(
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  relevancy double precision NOT NULL,
  data text,
  latitude double precision NOT NULL,
  longitude double precision NOT NULL
  CONSTRAINT event_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I tried `explain analyze` and got the following, which I think means the index isn't even used:

```
"Limit  (cost=1045499.02..1045499.27 rows=100 width=1249) (actual time=14842.560..14842.575 rows=100 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=1045499.02..1050710.90 rows=2084754 width=1249) (actual time=14842.557..14842.562 rows=100 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: relevancy"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 351kB"
"        ->  Seq Scan on event  (cost=0.00..965821.22 rows=2084754 width=1249) (actual time=3090.660..12525.695 rows=1983213 loops=1)"
"              Filter: ((latitude >= 0::double precision) AND (latitude <= 180::double precision) AND (longitude >= 0::double precision) AND (longitude <= 180::double precision))"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 3334584"
"Total runtime: 14866.532 ms"
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3 on Win7 and it seems like overkill to move to anything else for this seemingly simple task.

Questions:

- Any ways to use different indexes to help the current query be faster?
- Any ways to rewrite the current query to be faster?
- What's the easiest way to do this right? Install PostGIS and use the `GEOGRAPHY`data type? Is that going to actually provide a performance benefit to what I'm doing now? Which PostGIS function would work best for this query?

---

Edit #1: Results for `vacuum full analyze`:

```
INFO:  vacuuming "public.event"
INFO:  "event": found 0 removable, 5397347 nonremovable row versions in 872213 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet.
CPU 17.73s/11.84u sec elapsed 154.24 sec.
INFO:  analyzing "public.event"
INFO:  "event": scanned 30000 of 872213 pages, containing 185640 live rows and 0 dead     rows; 30000 rows in sample, 5397344 estimated total rows
Total query runtime: 360092 ms.
```

Results after the vacuum:

```
"Limit  (cost=1058294.92..1058295.17 rows=100 width=1216) (actual time=6784.111..6784.121 rows=100 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=1058294.92..1063405.89 rows=2044388 width=1216) (actual time=6784.109..6784.113 rows=100 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: relevancy"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 203kB"
"        ->  Seq Scan on event  (cost=0.00..980159.88 rows=2044388 width=1216) (actual time=0.043..6412.570 rows=1983213 loops=1)"
"              Filter: ((latitude >= 0::double precision) AND (latitude <= 180::double precision) AND (longitude >= 0::double precision) AND (longitude <= 180::double precision))"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 3414134"
"Total runtime: 6784.170 ms"
```

Comment: I agree the index isn't getting used. The index ddl and query look fine to me. can you try updating stats on the table? this cost `cost=0.00..965821.22` looks wildly inaccurate to me. Perhaps you just dumped data into the table before running the query.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using? I have seen seq scans on tables with `uuid` columns sometimes to be fairly slow. Can you try an `integer` column for ID and see if that changes anything? I guess the reason for the index not being used is the fact that the `where` condition still returns nearly 2 million rows (out of 5.3 million). Postgres will usually only use an index if less than roughly 15% of the rows will be returned by the condition.

Comment: Andreas, I did a `vacuum full analyze` and reported results above, in Edit #1.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I'm using Postgres 9.3 on Windows 7 64-bit. 

I'm not sure I'm keen to migrate to integer primary keys - a seq scan will be too slow in any case, even if it gets faster when using ints.

The idea about too many rows being returned is interesting - but what can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be much better off using a spatial index which uses an R-tree (essentially a two-dimensional index, which operates by dividing the space into boxes), and will perform far better than greater than, less than comparisons on two separate lat, lon values on this kind of query. You will need to create a geometry type first though, which you then index and use in your query instead of the separate lat/lon pairs you are currently using.

The following will create a geometry type, populate it, and add an index to it, ensuring that it is a point and in lat/lon, known as EPSG:4326

```
alter table event add column geom geometry(POINT, 4326);
update event set geom=ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(lon, lat), 4326);
create index ix_spatial_event_geom on event using gist(geom);
```

Then you can run the following query to get your events, which will use a spatial intersects, which should utilize your spatial index:

```
Select * from events where ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeBox2D(ST_MakePoint(swLon, swLat), 
    ST_MakePoint(neLon, neLat)),4326), geom) 
order by relevancy desc limit 100;
```

You make the bounding box for your intersection by using ST_MakeBOX2D with two sets of points, which will be on diagonal corners of the bounding box, so the SW and NE or the NW and SE pairs, would both work.

When you run explain on this, you should find that the spatial index is included. This will perform vastly better than two separate indexes on lon and lat columns, as you are only hitting one indexed, optimized for spatial search, rather than two B-trees. I realize that this represents another way of doing it and does not answer you original question, except indirectly.

**EDIT:** Mike T has made the very good point that for bounding box searches in 4326, it is more appropriate and quicker to use a geometry data type and the && operator as the SRID will be ignored anyway, eg,

```
 where ST_MakeBox2D(ST_MakePoint(swLon, swLat), ST_MakePoint(neLon, neLat)) && geom
```

Comment: This looks promising, thanks (actually answers the third bullet point I listed - I suspected this would be the right way to do it). I will get home and test it.

But a quick question - why use `Geometry` type rather than `Geography` type? I read http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6681/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-postgis-geography-and-geometry-types but I'm still not sure which would be best for my use case. In theory the data seems more fitting to `Geography`.

Comment: See here: http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ch04.html#PostGIS_GeographyVSGeometry for a quick comparison. Generally there are more functions available for the geometry type, but geography is better if you have data spanning the globe, as it will deal with things like the date line. I am not sure what is your exact use case, but ST_Intersects will work with either geometry or geography. You can always run a test with one against the other :D

Comment: Thanks, preliminary testing shows that this helps quite a bit (mapping to Spring JPA will be tough though). 

I'm still unclear what indices would work best here - I did one on `relevancy desc` and another on `gist(location)`, but should I have done two-column indexes instead for both columns and if yes, then is it for both `relevancy desc,gist(location)` and `gist(location),relevancy desc` or just one of these options? This is assuming I need both 'narrow' and 'wide' queries. I suppose all this should be answered by testing, just though maybe someone with your experience can tell immediately.

Comment: Yes, I thought it would help rather a lot. I can't help with Spring JPA, though :-( Generally speaking, the Postgres query optimizer does a really good job in my experience. I would think that the spatial index will narrow your results down much faster than relevancy. What does explain say now with an ST_Intersects query?

Comment: For very wide queries, explain says it uses the `relevancy` index.

And narrow ones don't behave well at all now, `explain analyze Select * from record where ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeBox2D(ST_MakePoint(-60, -60), ST_MakePoint(-59, -59)), 4326), location) 
order by relevancy desc limit 100;` is running now for a few minutes and not returning. :/

But I used Geography - maybe I need to use some other functions...

Comment: I needed to run `vacuum` for some reason. So now it actually does an index scan on the `gist` index and is fast.

Comment: I'm not certain it handles date line properly, but that's for another question.

Comment: Yes, vacuum and analyze are part of the black arts of Postgres. If explain doesn't show a spatial index being used on such a query, it is a sure sign something is wrong and you need to update statistics.

Comment: If all that is need is bbox overlaps, the [`&&` operator](http://postgis.net/docs/geometry_overlaps.html) is most direct, and is indirectly used by `ST_Intersects(geometry, geometry)`. I.e. `where ST_MakeBox2D(ST_MakePoint(swLon, swLat), ST_MakePoint(neLon, neLat)) && geom` (SRIDs are ignored by this operator).

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out. I also recently realized that despite my hopes it doesn't handle queries spanning more than half of the world properly (it takes the "opposite" side of globe instead). Not sure if that's how ST_MakeBox2D works or something else.

Comment: No, ST_MakeBox2D is just a quick shortcut for making a Polygon out of two points, and has no direct bearing on date lines, geom vs geog, etc.

Comment: Mike, I tried your suggestion (had to cast `geography` to `geometry` for it to work) and it works slower than the `ST_Intersects`.

Comment: OTOH once I construct `ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POLYGON((...))')` and then do `&&` then this works fast. Still doesn't handle the issue when queries span more than half of the globe, I will create a different question for it.

Comment: I have updated the original answer to include the geography and && operator suggestion of Mike T.

Comment: I've posted the other question:

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102425/find-out-whether-geography-point-lies-within-geography-bounds