# Join tables on a geo range

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have 2 independent tables (Links & Sections). The information inside link table is somewhat like this,

```
Links Table
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    id    |    Description    | startLat | startLng | endLat   | endLng   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1000259  | Link Number 1     |52.891372 |-1.768254 |52.892545 |-1.775278 |
| 1000359  | Link Number 2     |52.894892 |-1.780513 |52.894306 |-1.774793 |
| 1000279  | Link Number 3     |52.894306 |-1.774793 |52.895000 |-1.765273 |
| 1000258  | Link Number 4     |52.895000 |-1.765273 |52.895500 |-1.755278 |
| 1000255  | Link Number 5     |52.895500 |-1.755278 |52.896500 |-1.745278 |
| 1000555  | Link Number 6     |52.896500 |-1.745278 |52.897250 |-1.735278 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And the Sections table appears like this,

```
Sections Table
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    id    | Description    | fromLat    | fromLng    | toLat    | toLng    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 625      | Section 1      | 52.893598  | -1.775120  | 52.885053|-1.756409 |
| 713      | Section 2      | 52.897273  | -1.788324  | 52.898285|-1.724721 |
| ...      | ...            | ...        | ...        | ...      | ...      |
| ...      | ...            | ...        | ...        | ...      | ...      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to run a query which gives me all the links which are covered by a section. So if I say how many links come under Section 2, I should receive all the links that are covered by the lat/lng of section information.

P.S. Please note, Sections are longer than Links ... Any Help!!!

Comment: should section and link be on the same line or how do you know that link is on/within the section?

Answer (score 2):

You do this with a `join`, just the conditions are inequalities rather than equalities.  It is unclear whether you want partial coverage or total coverage.  Here is an example for partial coverage:

```
select s.*, l.*
from sections s join
     links l
     on (l.startlat < s.tolat and l.endlast > s.fromlat) and
        (l.startlong < s.tolong and l.endlong > s.fromlong);
```

Comment: This will work, but if you are using Postgres, you should really consider using Postgis and its related spatial functions. You can use a spatial index (R-tree) and functions like ST_Intersects, ST_Contains which will significantly outperform a series of < and > operators on a  couple of numeric fields with B-trees. There would be some overhead in converting your 4 columns to 2 (lat/lon) points, but for any significant table size, this effort will be worth it.

Comment: This was my answer to a somewhat similar question a while back. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212355/query-by-coordinates-takes-too-long-options-to-optimize/24218861#24218861

Comment: @JohnBarça: For simple cases (small areas that can be treated as flat), you can do much without Postgis. A GiST index on boxes or circles supports the [contains operator `<@`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-geometry.html#FUNCTIONS-GEOMETRY-OP-TABLE).

Comment: @Erwin. True. I always forget about the built in Postgres functions. A case of using a bulldozer to move a brick, I suppose on this case. Postgis is so powerful, I find it hard to avoid the recommendation.