# Spatial data and functional indexes

Tags: postgresql, geolocation, geospatial

I'm quite new on PostgreSQL.

I'm trying to create a spatial functional index that lets me order database entries based on a relevancy function that I defined that depends on an arbitrary location and on information included in the entries, that also includes location information.

This means that the Index depends both on parameters defined at the moment of making the query and parameters defined by the information on each entry on the database.

For what I have read this is the way to go as the complexities of maintaining an index are handled automatically by PostgreSQL and scalability is better ensured.

On creating this kind of spatial functional index I was only able to find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24212355/3128369), but it is not too clear to me given my inexperience with PostgreSQL.

Do you know of a good resource/tutorial where I can learn how to make spatial funcional indexes?